# Клавиатура наезжает на TextField и не видно вводимого текста

Tags: libgdx, android

TextField находится снизу экрана, и при тапе, на Android вызывается клавиатура, и клавиатура наезжает сверху TextField, как это пофиксить? В Android SDK автоматически поднимается экран, чтобы TextField был над клавиатурой.

Answer (score 4):

В активность следует добавить свойство:

```
<activity name="ActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

или так:

```
<activity name="ActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
</activity>
```

**[Ссылка](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)**

Comment: Это не работает с libGDX